# servicedesk plus - webflux - curl (api3)

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Get request working like charm for curl

```
curl http://{SDP_BASE_URL}/api/v3/requests/{request_id} \
      -H "TECHNICIAN_KEY: FC645540-6424-4A07-8A05-A865F4B8168A" \
```

Code for webflux is:

```
WebClient.create().get()
     .uri("https://server/api/v3/requests/{id}?TECHNICIAN_KEY={api_key}", id, TECHNICAL_KEY)
     .retrieve()
     .toEntity(Request.class)
     .block()
     .getBody()
     .getRequest();​
```

But for POST api/v3/requests

```
 curl http://{SDP_BASE_URL}/api/v3/requests \
      -H "TECHNICIAN_KEY: FC645540-6424-4A07-8A05-A865F4B8168A" \
      -d 'input_data= {
    "request": {
        "subject": "Unable to fetch mails",
        "description": "I am unable to fetch mails from the mail server",
        "requester": {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "administrator"
        },
        "impact_details": "Routine tasks are pending due to mail server problem",
        "resolution": {
            "content": "Mail Fetching Server problem has been fixed"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "Open"
        }
    }
}'
```

I got problems using webflux:

```
WebClient.create().post()
            .uri("https://server/api/v3/requests/?TECHNICIAN_KEY={api_key}", TECHNICAL_KEY)
            .bodyValue(request)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(res -> res.bodyToMono(Request.class))
            .subscribe(obj -> System.out.println("POST: " + obj.getRequest()));
```

I dont know how to present using webClient line:

```
-d 'input_data= {
```

Comment: its all in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client

Comment: still got prolem with converting curl to webflux...

Comment: we are not going to write your code for you. `But how to post now - any tips?`the tip was easy. Read the documentation, especially the section on how to make a post call with webflux. We are talking this is the absolut basics of webflux. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body you have to at least try

Comment: I think without postman app I would got problems all the time with bad request. Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.

Using postman i checked required fields.

And by using:

```
final MultiValueMap<String, Request> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
formData.add("input_data", request);
```

Now everything works fine.